# How to remove this title from mini ToCs?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, tufte

How to remove "Whatever it is" from just the two mini ToCs? (I want it to remains in the main ToC.)

```
\documentclass[notoc]{tufte-book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}

\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}

\section{Historical Overview}
\section{The CUDA Model}
\section{A Lattice Boltzmann Solver}

\stopcontents[chapters]% doesn't work
\addtocontents{toc}{Whatever it is\endgraf}
\resumecontents[chapters]% doesn't work

\chapter{Foo Bar}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\section{My Overview}
In this chapter we first...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to associate the "random text" within the ToC as being some form of sectional unit. Just like you have `chapter`, `section`, ..., let's call it `special`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[notoc]{tufte-book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\l@special}[2]{#1\endgraf}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}

\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}

\section{Historical Overview}
\section{The CUDA Model}
\section{A Lattice Boltzmann Solver}

\stopcontents[chapters]
\addcontentsline{toc}{special}{Whatever it is}
\resumecontents[chapters]

\chapter{Foo Bar}
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\section{My Overview}
In this chapter we first...
\end{document}
```

We define `\l@special` to handle the special entry in the ToC... in this case, just write whatever it contains.